# How to have cron delete file sizes over certain size

Tags: cron, cpanel

Can someone please tell me what command line to input into cron to delete all files in a certain directory over a certain size.  Thank you

(I'm on an apache server... and I'm using the cpanel cron program)

Comment: I figured it out.  Here is the command I put into cron to delete all files in this directory that is over 150kb:  find public_html/wp-content/uploads/bpfb/* -size +153600c -type f -delete 

(obviously the directory will be replaced with your own directory; and the 153600 number is in bits)

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
find path/to/directory -type f -size +150k
```

for specifying file size in kb. In case you need limit in MB some other day, use `150M` instead.

The current command will delete all files within that directory and its subdirectory, so you *may* want to use the `maxdepth` option for deleting files within a directory and not in its subdirectories

```
find path/to/directory -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +150k
```

Comment: Adding the following option will forcefully delete all the results of the command "--exec rm -rfv {} +"